# How to properly parse strings in a text file in my format

Tags: ruby, parsing

I am trying to parse/organize a list of strings line by line from a text file into an array that is in Ruby. I hope I explained that right.

example.txt

```
exampleuser:examplepassword
myusername:mypassword
askfjwaeir:dcqw38974q238ifj
```

How I want to store example.txt in Ruby -

```
$username = [ "exampleuser",
      "myusername",
      "askfjwaeir"
]

$password = [ "examplepassword",
      "mypassword",
      "dcqw38974q238ifj"
```

I've been searching for a couple hours but can't seem to find anything to what I'm looking for. I know about .strip, .split, cutting off from the semicolon, but I cannot seem to do what I described here.

Answer (score 0):

```
username, password = File.readlines('example.txt')
                         .map { |s| s.chomp.split(':') }
                         .transpose
```

Why would you have such a presentation in the first place? The hash having usernames as keys and passwords as values in way more readable:

```
users = File.readlines('example.txt')
            .map { |s| s.chomp.split(':') }
            .to_h
#⇒ {
#   "exampleuser" => "examplepassword",
#    "myusername" => "mypassword",
#    "askfjwaeir" => "dcqw38974q238ifj"
# }
```

Also, under no circumstances, one should use global variables.

Comment: So the need of global variables are completely not necessary?

Comment: If and only one has something really _global_, like `$stdin`, it makes sense.

Comment: Okay, make sense!

Comment: Global variables have their place, and you can't know what refactorings might be needed to get rid of them based solely on the original post. It's fine to *recommend* that they be avoided for namespacing or data encapsulation, but don't assume you know enough about the lexical scope to make such a sweeping statement without seeing the rest of the OP's code.

Comment: @CodeGnome I do not need to see the rest of the OP’s code to make such a sweeping statement, when I see **the assignment** of globals. It’s not about the usage of globals deeply inside legacy code. It is the assignment. Hence, globals could be easily avoided. That simple.

Answer (score 0):

### Use a Deconstructing Assignment

One way to deal with the question you asked is to use [IO#each_line](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-each_line) inside a self-closing [File#open](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/File.html#method-c-open) block. You can then deconstruct each line with [String#split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-split), and then append the results of to your storage arrays. For example:

```
# Create arrays outside the File block, which acts as a scope gate.
usernames = []
passwords = []

# Open your file, and split your lines. This solution avoids having to read
# all of example.txt in at once, which may matter on larger files.
File.open('example.txt') do |file|
  file.each_line do |line|
    user, pass = line.chomp.split ':'
    usernames << user
    passwords << pass
  end
end

usernames
#=> ["exampleuser", "myusername", "askfjwaeir"]

passwords
#=> ["examplepassword", "mypassword", "dcqw38974q238ifj"]
```

### Use a Hash Instead

The example above answers the question you asked, but it's probably the solution to an X/Y problem because you now lack a mapping between usernames and passwords. You could index between two arrays, but that's really cumbersome. What you really want is a key/value data structure like a Hash.

Given the output from the previous example, you can use [Array#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-zip) and [Array#to_h](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-to_h) to convert the array data into something more useful. For example:

```
# Map usernames and passwords to a hash.
user_pass_mapping = usernames.zip(passwords).to_h

# Look up the password for the given user.
user_pass_mapping.dig 'myusername'
#=> "mypassword"

# Look up the user by the (obviously unencrypted) password.
user_pass_mapping.rassoc('examplepassword').first
#=> "exampleuser"
```

Maybe you have a specific use case, but in general you should pick a data structure based on how you plan to *access* your data. In most cases, key/value pairs should be a Hash, Struct, or OpenStruct, as they are optimized for finding keys. Your mileage may vary.